# Is there a way to permute a subset of a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, permutation

I'm working on a way to find the lowest 1-Norm of a given Matrix using a permutation of its rows. The problem is that the permutation can't be fully random. There are 4 subsets of rows in the Matrix having a special parameter. I want to permute just the rows having this one parameter and keeping those on the same spot.

Ex. The first column defines the type of row.

```
A = [ 

      1,   val_11, val_12, ...   #1. Row

      2,   val_21, val_22, ...   #2. Row

      2,   val_31, val_32, ...   #3. Row

      2,   val_41, val_42, ...   #4. Row

      1,   val_51, val_52, ...   #5. Row
]
```

So in this example I want to permute the 1. and 5. Row AND permute the 2., 3. and 4. Row keeping the Types like [1;2;2;2;1] in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to carefully define your permutations. Fancy indexing will then do the job :

Example :

```
from numpy.random import randint
M0 = randint(10,size=(5,5))
after=[4,2,3,1,0]
M0 = M[after]
print(M0)
print(M)

[[4 9 3 0 0]
 [3 1 7 6 0]
 [6 6 5 0 9]
 [0 4 7 1 3]
 [0 0 1 0 6]]

[[0 0 1 0 6]
 [6 6 5 0 9]
 [0 4 7 1 3]
 [3 1 7 6 0]
 [4 9 3 0 0]]
```